# SwagQL - Unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: node.js, rest, graphql, swagger

I followed the instructions in https://medium.com/groupon-eng/swagql-582df83f7d19 and was able to generate a GraphQL schema from my Swagger documentation, start an Express node.js server and open GraphiQL locally on my browser.

The problem is, when I try to query any of my endpoints I keep getting the following error:

> unable to verify the first certificate

Is there a simple way I can pass my **api_key** into GraphQL so that my queries are authenticated correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone having the same problem, I was able to bypass the error message by issuing a provider certificate and associating it to my site's binding in iis, then using the new qualified hostname as the Gofer baseUrl in the node.js client app.